# Convert c++ to VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, raspberry-pi, raspbian, windows-10-iot-core

We have working c++ code that works perfectly on Raspbian which is based on Debian. We want to convert it to VC++. But we see problem like how to get libraries:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

using namespace std;

#include "base64.h"

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>
```

If I copy header files from Raspbian OS, would it be working with VC++(Windows 10 IoT) or it would create problems?

Please advise, what is best way to deal with libraries used above?

Thanks

Comment: "If I copy header files from Raspbian OS, would it be working with VC++" - no.

Answer (score 1):

No, it'll not work if you copy files from raspbian. You have to use library which is equivalent for windows. For example, the equivalent of `#include <sys/socket.h>` in windows it is `#include <winsock2.h>`. You can use compile time condition code blocks. For example -

```
#ifdef _WIN32 //true for all windows
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
```

You can also write other codes using this type of condition. First of all you need to find out what are the alternatives of functions and libraries in windows you are using in debian.

Comment: Visual C++ (aka MSVC) governs the compiler itself, but not the available system headers or others available on the system. Thus there is no "equivalent" header on another compiler, except for the standardized language library headers.

Comment: @tambre I meant equivalent for windows. Sorry for the mistake. Editing it.

Comment: @tambre: Actually, MSVC **does** include the available system headers. These are part of the so-called "Windows SDK".

Comment: @MSalters MSVC doesn't, it's an additional optional component during VS15 installation. You ver much install MSVC without installing the Windows SDK on VS15.